# How to make the pointer in VR game Loading while pointing on object?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am trying to change the pointer while pointing (make it load like loading circle ) on object with timer.

I set the timer and it worked and I found this code but i didn't know how to set it with unity in the inspector like where should I put this code and how can I edit the circle

```
`while (circle.fillAmount < 1)
        {
            circle.fillAmount += 0.05f;
            amount = circle.fillAmount;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0);
        }`
```

Comment: What are you asking? What is the issue exactly? Please rephrase and add more detail.

Comment: @Katianie I am asking where to put the code also in the VR game there's the GvrReticlePointer code

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you are saying. You need to narrow down your question and provide more code as to where the error is happening.